# How to send GET request in Hindi using Volley?

Tags: php, android

[image to show it is not taking rabi as url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gtfoT.png)

Here is my Android code to get data from web service where `type=खरीफ`.When I check it using `Postman`it is working. But when I check it with android it is not working.

```
String GET_JSON_DATA_HTTP_URL = "http://ddagroindore.com/webservice/GetFasal.php?type=";

 public void JSON_DATA_WEB_CALL(){
    String s = getIntent().getStringExtra("RABI");

    String URL = GET_JSON_DATA_HTTP_URL+s;
    Log.d(TAG, "JSON_DATA_WEB_CALL: "+URL);

    jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest( URL,

            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

                    JSON_PARSE_DATA_AFTER_WEBCALL(response);
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            });

    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
}
```

Log.d

> JSON_DATA_WEB_CALL: [http://ddagroindore.com/webservice/GetFasal.php?type=खर](http://ddagroindore.com/webservice/GetFasal.php?type=%E0%A4%96%E0%A4%B0)ीफ

**GetFasal.php**

```
    <?php

        require_once 'include/DB_Config.php';

// Create connection
$conn =new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);
$conn->set_charset("utf8");

 //$conn = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME) or die('Unable to Connect');


if ($conn->connect_error) {
 die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET'){

        $type  = $_GET['type'];
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM fasals WHERE type='".$type."'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows >0) {
 // output data of each row
 while($row[] = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

 $tem = $row;

 $json = json_encode($tem, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);


 }

} else {
 echo "0 results";
}
 echo $json;
$conn->close();
}
?>
```

Comment: What is `JSON_PARSE_DATA_AFTER_WEBCALL(response);`? Is that method not being called?

Comment: `JSON_PARSE_DATA_AFTER_WEBCALL(response);`  to set data to an adapter which is working fine. Problem is with sending url request to server

Comment: What is the problem specifically? Any errors?

Comment: no error message

Comment: view edit image to show it is not taking rabi as url

Comment: Post code that shows this being done

Comment: make sure the page has UTF-8 character encoding

Comment: ` String s = getIntent().getStringExtra("RABI");


        String query = null;
        try {
            query = URLEncoder.encode(s, "utf-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String URL = GET_JSON_DATA_HTTP_URL+query;`

Comment: encode your parameter as **s=URLEncoder.encode(s, "UTF-8")** and try

Comment: now its working thankyou everyone.